# How can I add elements to a card while hovering using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to add elements to a card while the mouse is hovering over the card (like netflix cards), however when the cursor is moved to where the new button appears the mouseout event is triggered and the button cannot be pressed. Here's an example:

```
<div class="cards">
    <img class="cardsImg" src="codePic.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>Project 1</h3>
    <div class="cardsDesc"></div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards');
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        cards[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            let desc = cards[i].querySelector('.cardsDesc')
            desc.innerHTML = `<div class="readMore" onmouseover="moveArrow('arrow1')" onmouseout="moveArrowBack('arrow1')">
            <a href="About.html" class="readMoreLink">Click here to read more <span id="arrow1">&#10132;</span></a>
            </div>`;
        })
        cards[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
            let desc = cards[i].querySelector('.cardsDesc')
            desc.innerHTML = ``;
        })
    }
})
```

I'm new to JavaScript, not sure what to try so any help is apprciated.

Comment: is image, h3 and cardDesc are all direct child of cards div?

Comment: Yes, and I'm trying to add elements inside cardDescs

Answer (score 0):

Try using mouseenter and mouseleave events. Working Example https://codepen.io/sethuramancbe/pen/poxoreK

```js
function moveArrow(arrow) {
  //your code
}
function moveArrowBack(arrow) {
//your code
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards');
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        cards[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            let desc = cards[i].querySelector('.cardsDesc')
            desc.innerHTML = `<div class="readMore" onmouseover="moveArrow('arrow1')" onmouseout="moveArrowBack('arrow1')">
            <a href="About.html" class="readMoreLink">Click here to read more <span id="arrow1">&#10132;</span></a>
            </div>`;
        })
        cards[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            let desc = cards[i].querySelector('.cardsDesc')
            desc.innerHTML = ``;
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <img class="cardsImg" src="codePic.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>Project 1</h3>
    <div class="cardsDesc"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards');
  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    let desc = cards[i].querySelector('.cardsDesc');
    cards[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
      desc.style.display = `block`;
    });
    cards[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
      desc.style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <img class="cardsImg" src="codePic.jpg" alt="" />
  <h3>Project 1</h3>
  <div class="cardsDesc" style="display: none">
    <div class="readMore">
      <a href="About.html" class="readMoreLink">Click here to read more <span id="arrow1">&#10132;</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the solution for your problem, you should define it like this to achieve it.
For any queries do let me know.
Thank you.